# Finding a user id from the URL in Wix and using it as a filter

Tags: dynamic, velo

I am attempting to filter repeater data and run query's based off a user's ID in a custom Wix user profile, but I can't work out how to identify a user's ID based upon the URL of the dynamic page (i.e. the user's username) instead of the current logged in user.

I have attempted to define the relevant user id both as the path of the URL and then run a query from that to identify the user ID, and by placing an invisible text box on the page with the relevant ID inside it based off a filtered collection, but neither have worked.